# Google maps geocode api free daily limit get over in one hit, it happening due to I not enable billing?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am hitting below URL to test my key

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=20.0041,73.7175&key=$key
```

it show this an error after one hit

```
{
error_message: "You have exceeded your daily request quota for this API. If you did not set a custom daily request quota, verify your project has an active billing account: http://g.co/dev/maps-no-account",
results:[],
status: "OVER_QUERY_LIMIT"
}
```

Please help me why it is happening, anything to do with enable billing?

Comment: I am facing same issue in Autocomplete Api here is the my URL :-https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=bb%@&types=city&location=%@,%@&radius=500&language=en&key=AIzaSyBniPutEX2z5uguUrWQJwIrDnTeyM9WNJ8

Comment: Did you enable billing?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because is is about Google's Terms of Use/Billing, not coding

Comment: after enable billing, error gone

Comment: @geocodezip the question is to use free quota we have to enable billing ?

Comment: If you read the documents, enabling billing is mandatory.  So yes.

Comment: @DilipMishra by enabling billing my problem solved, i tested for 2 days and working fine now

Comment: I have enabled billing and (₹2 + ₹50 + ₹50) cut from credit card and plan moved to **Blaze - Pay as you go** plan. is there another way to enable billing without pay? because I have many projects need to enable billing.

Comment: Do not close this question because it does not have a programmatic solution, some people like me are unaware of the reason behind this

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As stated in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51876818/google-map-geocode-api-free-daily-limit-get-over-in-one-hit-it-happening-due-to#comment90707221_51876818) to the question, you need to enable billing, even if you are only using the free quota. See the [docs about this change](http://g.co/dev/maps-no-account) for more information.